# Consultar las llaves foraneas de una tabla y a que llave primaria esta relacionada

Tags: sql-server

Alguien sabe como consultar las llaves foráneas de una tabla en SQL y a que llaves primarias hacen referencia?

Answer (score 1):

Sería algo como

```
SELECT   
    f.name AS foreign_key_name  
   ,OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS table_name  
   ,COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS constraint_column_name  
   ,OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS referenced_object  
   ,COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS referenced_column_name  
   ,is_disabled  
   ,delete_referential_action_desc  
   ,update_referential_action_desc  
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f  
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc   
   ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id   
WHERE f.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.tabla_magica');
```

reemplazando `dbo.tabla_magica` por tu esquema y tabla deseados

Comment: Eso funciona bien cuando no hay llaves primarias compuestas.

Comment: @Alfabravo Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La manera más rápida de verlo es ejecutando el procedimiento almacenado del sistema *sp_help* mediante el atajo del teclado ALT+F1, solo debes tener seleccionado el nombre de la tabla.
De esta manera puedes ver a qué base, tabla y llave primaria hace referencia cada llave foránea.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).